# Encrypting a string of arbitrary size with a big integer

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, stream-cipher

I am currently writing Python script that initiates a secure handshake. I am kind of reinventing the wheel here, so that I can properly learn it.

Now, I have Diffie-Hellman mostly working from scratch, and both client and server has agreed on a key to use. This key is an integer of ~2048 bits (2047 most of the time. 2046 is the lowest I've seen). The question then is, which cipher do I chose for encryption data of arbitrary length with this key?

Also, when the client and the server later has exchanged public keys, is there any reason why I should/should rely on said public key encryption alone, and not use the above mentioned integer as well?

Comment: The key size is too big for any symmetric cipher. Just use a KDF like HKDF to arrive a key for AES-128-192-256 and encrypt with at least AES-GCM or AES-GCM-SIV. Diffie-Hellman actually is a key agreement protocol. The sides are not exchanging their keys. There are lots of Q/A about this.

Comment: Well, all that is needed with that key is to encrypt/decrypt a public DSA key as part of the initial handshake. Are you saying that it cannot be done?

Comment: DSA is not encryption. It is the Digital Signature Algorithm. If you mean encrypt with a public key scheme then they are slow, and we prefer the hybrid encryption that is exchange keys and use a symmetric encryption scheme.

Comment: That's not what I am asking. I am exchanging DSA public keys, and I would like to encrypt these keys with a ~2048 bit integer. Are you saying this cannot be done?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt DSA public keys? That makes no sense as a thing to do. It's like encrypting the front page of the New York Times: already public and thus pointless to encrypt.

Comment: Anyone wanting to MITM and inject their own certificate during the initial exchange would not be able to do so by the time secure connection is establed.... but that's really outside of what my question was.

Comment: The initial exchange can be performed with certificates... If you don't trust use phone to make sure that the public keys are valid.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Diffie-Hellman *key agreement* protocol, both sides reach the equal keys. Then, you can use it with private key encryption methods, not public ones (like AES or one-time-pad).

One philosophy of public key encryptions is for avoiding key exchanges or key agreements. They are also called asymmetric encryption methods, because the sender and the receiver of the messages have different keys.